# Regex to exclude URLs that contain file paths

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match only URLs that does'n contain `?` char, that doesn't end with `\` char and that doesn't end with a file path (.jpg, .aspx etc - need to exclude all file extensions)

This is expected result:

1. Doesn't match - `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg`
2. Doesn't match - `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg/`
3. Match - `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test`
4. Doesn't match - `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test?v=ASAS77162UTNBYV77`

My regex - `[^.\?]*[^/]*^[^?]*[^/]$`, works well for most cases, but fail for this `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg` (matches, but it doesn't)

Comment: It does match the last one : https://regex101.com/r/07iO3o/1

Comment: Don't want match `http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
^(?!.*\?)(?!.*\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$).*[^/]$
```

This uses two negative lookaheads to meet your requirements:

```
(?!.*\?)                - no ? appears anywhere in the URL
(?!.*\/[^\/]+\.[^\/]+$) - no extension appears
```

The requirement for the URL not ending in a path separator is given literally, by matching that character at the every end of the URL.

```js
console.log(/^(?!.*\?)(?!.*\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$).*[^/]$/.test('http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test'));
console.log(/^(?!.*\?)(?!.*\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$).*[^/]$/.test('http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg'));
console.log(/^(?!.*\?)(?!.*\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$).*[^/]$/.test('http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test?v=ASAS77162UTNBYV77'));
console.log(/^(?!.*\?)(?!.*\/[^/]+\.[^/]+$).*[^/]$/.test('http://mywebsite.com/some-path/test.jpg/'));
```